# MacOS Mojave screenshot save settings

Tags: macos, screenshot, macos-mojave

In prior versions of MacOS, hitting Cmd-Shift-4 immediately gave you a crosshair, allowed you to choose a rectangle, and immediately saved the image to the desktop.  Now MacOS 10.14 Mojave shows a thumbnail of the image, and requires some time and an extra two clicks before saving the image.

How do I default the settings and always save the image immediately?

Answer (score 3):

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201361

If you have a trackpad or touchscreen, then swipe right on the thumbnail and it's saved immediately.  If you have a mouse, then drag the image to the right, and it's saved immediately.

To have the screenshots saved immediately, then hit Cmd-Shift-5, choose the Options menu at the bottom of the screen, and uncheck "Show Floating Thumbnail."

Comment: ...or the more obvious, also mentioned on that page - Options: uncheck Show Floating Thumbnail.

Comment: I'm searching that page, and don't find "uncheck"

Comment: Change the settings...
Click Options in the onscreen controls to change these settings : ...
Show Floating Thumbnail: Choose whether to show the thumbnail.

Comment: Found it.  Hit Cmd-Shift-5 .  Note the Options at the bottom of the screen (same color as the Dark theme night sands, so I missed it before).  In the Options menu, uncheck "Show Floating Thumbnail."  Updating the answer, thanks for the pointer.